# How to search for projects that have a particular dependency?

Tags: github, clojure

I'd like to find Clojure projects (perhaps on Github) that have a particular dependency. Is there a website that provides this search capability? Is there a way to do a search on Github across all Clojure projects far a particular string within a file (dependency description)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The https://crossclj.info site has an index that tracks project level dependencies and also function uses across libs.

You can use the Tentacles library to access the Github API from Clojure - here's a project with some additional code on top of Tentacles that makes a good example: https://github.com/slipset/get-profiles

Or you can use the Github search page to narrow in a variety of ways:

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=org.clojure%2Fclojure+language%3AClojure&type=Code&ref=searchresults